# Angularjs failed to load templateurl

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

here is the directive

```
moduleDirectives
.directive('barNotification', ['$compile', '$timeout', function ($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            barShow:'=',
            barType: '=',
            barMessage:'=',
            barAllowClose:'=',
            onClose: '&',
            onOpenSlopeSetting: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.contentElement = element;
            scope.onCloseExists = 'onCloser' in attr;
            scope.$watch('barMessage', function () {
                $timeout(
                        function () {
                            angular.element(scope.contentElement[0].querySelector('#barMessage')).replaceWith($compile('<div id="barMessage">' + scope.barMessage + '</div>')(scope));
                        });
            }, true);
        },
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Claim/Singlepage/directives/barnotification/barNotification.cshtml',
        controller: 'barNotificationController'
    };
}]);
```

Here is the project directory

[image]

When the app loads I get the following error.

> [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:
>   /Areas/Claim/Singlepage/directives/barnotification/test.cshtml (HTTP
>   status: 403 Forbidden)

What did I miss?

Comment: i notice the server response is 403, are you able to get the contents of the file by directly accessing them in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I suspected it is web.config issue. This is line the web.config `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />` ,  since the page that I am trying to load is  .cshtml IIS chocks on it.  removing this line from web.config or turning the value to true solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

your template is not loading because your url is absolute, look at how the url address starts `/Areas/Claim/Singlepage...`, so whenever the browser attempts to make an AJAX call to that url it will search for that exact url, you have to make the calls relative to the `baseUrl`

try removing the first slash `Areas/Claim/Singlepage...`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that before , same issue.  btw , I am using the exact directive on different project  and it works.  I am working on a new project and trying to reuse the code but stuck on this issue. I am suspecting something to do with web.config but no clue yet.

Comment: have you checked on the networking log?, can you see if it's making the calls from the relative baseURL?

Comment: information: 
    Process ID: 11772 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: IIS APPPOOL\claimClient 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: Path '/Areas/Claim/Singlepage/directives/barnotification/barNotification.cshtml' is forbidden.
   at System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Comment: this seems to be a server issue, not an angular request fail, try to get the content of the file by directly requesting the file in the browser, if it still gives the same error, then check the config of the server to see if there are allowed permissions to access the directory

Comment: Thanks but I figured it out. As I suspected it is web.config issue.          <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" /> ,  since the page that I am trying to load is  .cshtml IIS chocks on it.  removing this line from web.config or turning the value to true solved the issue. Thanks a lot for your effort.I appreciated it a lot.